# How to reset a Guzzle client and clear any cached values (memory usage)

Tags: php, guzzle

I have code similar to what's below (it's example code). Using Guzzle, I make multiple calls to the same site to see if a document exists. If the document exists, I save it. As I make each call, the memory usage goes up. Eventually, if the number of requests is high enough, I run out of memory. I used `memory_get_peak_usage` to track where the memory use was happening, and it's the Guzzle client.

The code works as expected, but I cannot find a way to tell the Guzzle Client to "reset and dump all previous requests". I'm pretty sure it's caching the results in memory, but as I've written them out to a file, I know I won't be needing said results. How do I dump them?

FWIW, my current solution is making a new client duplicating the parameters of the original one, and unsetting it periodically. It works, but it's ugly.

```
    $client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client('some_url');
    for ($i=0; $i<10000; $i++)
    {
        try {
            $pdf = $client->get( $pdf_name )->send();
            $this->filesystem->put(
                $pdf_name,
                $pdf->getBody( true )
            );
        } catch ( ClientErrorResponseException $ex ) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you limited to using Guzzle v3 or are you able to use v5?  There were some significant architectural changes made under the hood. in v4 and v5

Comment: Didn't even think to check it. Guzzle is added via https://packagist.org/packages/misd/guzzle-bundle so I'll have to put some time into seeing if we can upgrade. But that gives me somewhere to start looking. Thanks.

Comment: To follow up my original question, is your error being exhibited within the context of a Symfony Framework application? Are your issues reproduceable from a test application (like your code sample)? Also, what is $this->filesystem?  Is it an instance of Symfony\Component\Filesystem?

Comment: I was able to answer my own question.  The $filesystem->put() method would actually seem to indicate usage of thephpleague/flysystem.

Comment: Not to leave you hanging: the filesystem is indeed `thephpleague/flysystem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a cursorary glance at the source code for the bundle the Guzzle client is making use of Doctrine's filesystem cache.  References:

- [Bundle/Resources/config/cache.xml](https://github.com/misd-service-development/guzzle-bundle/blob/master/Resources/config/cache.xml)
- [Bundle/DependencyInjection/MisdGuzzleExtension.php](https://github.com/misd-service-development/guzzle-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/MisdGuzzleExtension.php#L80)
- [Bundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php](https://github.com/misd-service-development/guzzle-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L42)

The Bundle documentation also provides information on [Caching](https://github.com/misd-service-development/guzzle-bundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/plugins.md#caching).  So, in theory to remove/disable the cache, all you have to do is remove the reference to `<argument type="service" id="misd_guzzle.cache.filesystem"/>` from the the addSubscriber section of your `MyBundle/Resources/config/services.xml`

Comment: I don't know if this is true in our case, because we don't have the cache enabled in that server; it's something I'll track down if I continue to have other problems.

Comment: But you were bang on with the version. We removed `misd/guzzle-bundle' from the project, and added `guzzlehttp/guzzle`. It meant a few changes in the code to handle different classes and exceptions but rerunning the code resulted in no errors for the same test case.

Comment: I'm using Guzzle 6 and notice that each ->get I do consumes close to 2MB of memory. I use the response right away so is there a way to "clear" the cache and regain the used memory?